# How can I set TestFlight test notes for XCode Cloud builds?

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration

By default, Xcode Cloud workflow provides no test notes for TestFlight uploads. I'd like to have string with git commit message and git commit hash instead of "No test notes" message.

Is it possible?

[image: testflight - no test notes - Xcode Cloud build]

Answer (score 3):

Xcode cloud can now populate the test notes from text files in your project directory under `TestFlight` folder.
For example, use `WhatToTest.en-US.txt` for U.S. English.

**Note** that the file has to include LOCALE in its name.

You can either use static text file or dynamically create one e.g. in your post build script.

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
#  ci_post_xcodebuild.sh


if [[ -d "$CI_APP_STORE_SIGNED_APP_PATH" ]]; then
  TESTFLIGHT_DIR_PATH=../TestFlight
  mkdir $TESTFLIGHT_DIR_PATH
  git fetch --deepen 3 && git log -3 --pretty=format:"%s" >! $TESTFLIGHT_DIR_PATH/WhatToTest.en-US.txt
fi
```

Full documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/including-notes-for-testers-with-a-beta-release-of-your-app

Comment: Have you gotten it to work, I keep seeing 

No “What to test” notes files found at /Volumes/workspace/repository

Comment: I've done some testing and it seems the "WhatToTest.<locale>.txt" files are deleted after the custom build script finishes execution. That's why they don't get picked up. I raised a feedback about this bug, @TommySadiqHinrichsen I suggest you do the same.

Comment: I've had essentially that example script running in a few projects for a few weeks now. Every build in TestFlight has had the notes set.
I'd recommend checking your folder structure and that the test notes are placed in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I know of:

1. Manually set the Test Details in App Store Connect. Unfortunately if you use Xcode Cloud to distribute the builds, they'll get distributed before you get a chance to set the Test Details.
2. Set them using [Fastlane's Pilot](http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pilot/#parameters) with a Fastfile lane such as:

```rb
build_number = latest_testflight_build_number
testflight(
    app_version: "1.0.0",
    build_number: build_number,
    groups: ["Your external testing group"],
    distribute_external: true,
    distribute_only: true,
    changelog: "We changed something in this build"
)
```

**important** Since Xcode Cloud automatically increments the build number, you have to get it yourself using `latest_testflight_build_number`.

Note that fastlane refers to the 'Test Details' as 'changelog', and they're also sometimes referred to as 'Test Notes', but on ASC they're 'Test Details'.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. Though I'm still looking for a vanilla way, I would investigate option with Fastlane as a workaround.

Comment: have you found a way to add test notes via xcode cloud ?

Comment: Hi @ALKINÇAKIRALAR this is exactly what my answer describes – the lack of ability to do so automatically. If Apple changes this, I'll update the answer.